# System architecture when using inmemory objects?

Tags: .net, architecture, chat, distributed-system, azure-load-balancer

I have created a stranger chat web application using .net core and jquery and signalR. Currently I am using dictionary to store connectionid and message for users. I am using the in memory object dictionary and not using any database.For testing perspective, I have deployed it on azure and It is working fine for 3-4 users. My questions are

1.Let's say If my application has 3000 users chatting at a time ,what would be best solution to host the application? My thought process is that I can take multiple system and using the load balancer, I can redirect them to different system. For example lets say there are 1500 users then each server can have 500 users in memory object and those 500 users can chat with each others. I can see one limitation that each users can chat with only those 500 users and not 1500 users. Is this solution feasible?

2.How much Ram/CPU core/storage would I required to handle 3000 users at the same time?

3.Do I need to use elastic search db instead of in memory objects to store messages.? I don't need to store message but would elastic search db help with distributed System?.

4.What are the best ways to use load balancer? and also How many distributed system would I require in my case?

My application supports chatting with strangers,uploading image,videos.

I know this can vary and we cannot tell it accurately but I would like to know the best possible System architecture for my web application.

Comment: You're talking systems architecture now. You'd need a load balancer, and a distributed cache such as redis at a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scale this, I would look out for a PubSub/Realtime database.
Examples are: Firebase Real-Time Database, Kafka Streams, Redis.

With this, it might be that you do not need any custom backend at all.

If you opt for own servers as a middleware for the pubsub, everything becomes way more complex. You would have to find a way to manage your infrastructure (e.g. with Kubernetes) and set up a Load Balancer (e.g. HAProxy) which distributes the requests among the servers.

There are providers like codesphere.com or heroku.com which make this process easier for you.

In addition to that you could serve your frontends via a cdn like cloudflare.com, netlify, or vercel in a scalable and easy way.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, the current solution is frontend talking to backend using SignalR and then backend talking to frontend for another user?

The main concern at the moment is the storage, so you would need to extract this into a separate place. Since it's a kind of a cache to store connection details, Redis, or another caching mechanism, would be perfect for that. Then the backend would just communicate with Redis whenever it needs some info.

Second concern is the connection count, since you would have more users. You would need to scale the backend to support that. I am not sure about how Azure works with that, but I am sure it does support it, I would assume there is some kind of a setting to scale the service and use some kind of load balancing strategy such as round robin. Since we don't have to remember which service the user connects to, that should work.

Regarding the message history, you mentioned that you don't store it, and the user would lose it whenever he reloads the app. If you need some kind of a lightweight message storage, you can think about local storage on the web browser. The messages could be stored locally and you would not need to worry about that in the backend. Otherwise, if you come to need to store the messages, then I think a nosql DB would be good for that, since you would just store blobs with a user id and message id. As you said, Elastic would be a good fit for that.

To answer your questions:

1. Is solved by extracting storage to a cache.
2. Difficult to say, you would need to just monitor the Azure services. However, since you could make the app scalable, you should be able to act on it once the limit is reached.
3. As mentioned previously, up to you how the app wants to behave, but if you need some kind of storage, either localstorage on the client side or some kind of nosql database would fit this purpose.
4. Load balancing should be available in Azure and you would just need to pick some kind of strategy to balance the load.